# Create new text at specific time

Tags: javascript, random, time

Is there a way to create a random number at a specific time?

For example on Monday at 7.30am "number1" should be shown.

On Monday 8.30 "number2" should be shown.

On Monday at 9.30 "number3" should be shown.

All I found is
https://www.askdavetaylor.com/can_i_change_my_web_page_based_on_time_of_day/
but I can't make it work for my problem.

I can't make the minute part work.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var thedate   = new Date();
var dayofweek = thedate.getUTCDay();
var hourofday = thedate.getUTCHours();
var minutesday = thedate.getMinutes();
    
    
function Stunde1()
{
// return TRUE if it's Mon through Sat, 3a-6a UTC
if (dayofweek != 2 && (hourofday >7 && hourofday <8) && (minutesday >31) ) 
{ return true;}
return false; }
    
function Stunde2()
{
// return TRUE if it's Mon through Sat, 3a-6a UTC
if (dayofweek != 2 && (hourofday > 7 && hourofday < 9) && (minutesday >31) ) 
{ return true;}
return false; }
    
function Stunde3()
{
// return TRUE if it's Mon through Sat, 3a-6a UTC
if (dayofweek != 2 && hourofday > 9 && minutesday >30 && hourofday <11 ) 
{ return true;}
return false; }
    
function Stunde4()
{
// return TRUE if it's Mon through Sat, 3a-6a UTC
if (dayofweek != 2 && (hourofday > 11 && hourofday < 13) && (minutesday <31) ) 
{ return true;}
return false; }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
if (Stunde1()) { document.write("<h2>Stunde1</h2>");} 
else if (Stunde2()) { document.write("<h2>Stunde2</h2>");} 
else if (Stunde3()) { document.write("<h2>Stunde3</h2>");} 
else if (Stunde4()) { document.write("<h2>Stunde4</h2>");} 
else {
document.write("<h2>kaputt</h2>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but we expect that you'll make an attempt and show what you've tried along with a ***specific*** question about what you are having a problem with.

Comment: I cant make it work with the minutes part.

Comment: Note that whenever you have the construct `if (condition) { return true; }  return false;` you can rewrite it as just `return condition;` or `return !!condition;` if you require an actual Boolean value.